# Microservice hosted on Cumulocity

Tags: json, docker, microservices, cumulocity

I'm trying to host a microservice on Cumulocity. I use the following article http://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/microservice-package/

I have created and started my container locally via my dockerfile without any problems.

- /docker/Dockerfile
- /docker/* - all files within the directory will be included in the docker build
- /cumulocity.json

Content of cumulocity.json:

```
{
"apiVersion":"1",
"version":"1.0",
"provider": {
  "name":"Hello World"
  },
  "isolation":"MULTI_TENANT",
  "requiredRoles": [
  ],
  "roles":[
  ]
}
```

When trying to pack the container via **$microservice pack -n hello-world**
Error: **[ERROR] Stopped: missing cumulocity.json in work directory: /Users/MyUser/Documents/HelloWorld**

The directory HelloWorld contains the above mentioned data structure with all files, also the missing cumulocity.json file is located with the correct file name. I have already executed the Microservice script inside and outside this folder structure.

Does this mistake look known to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

If there are other users interested - at the moment the **microservice** solution only runs on Linux. I have executed the command directly via my Ubuntu terminal - it works.

```
$microservice pack -n example
```

The example.zip file can then be hosted on Cumulocity as a microservice.

Answer (score -1):

Microservice build script works on Linux and MacOs environments.